# Accessing dotnetcore middleware AFTER a JWT Token is validated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, jwt

I am using JWT bearer authentication, configured as follows.

> My problem is that the middleware is executing before the token is validated.
>   **How do I configure the middleware to run afterwards?**

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie(_ => _.SlidingExpiration = true)
    .AddJwtBearer(
        _ =>
        {
            _.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                // THIS CODE EXECUTES AFTER THE MIDDLEWARE????
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                        new ClaimsIdentity(context.Principal.Claims, "local"));
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
            _.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            _.SaveToken = false;
            _.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidIssuer = this.Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = this.Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.Configuration["Tokens:Key"])),
            };
        });
```

I am attempting to add middleware into the pipeline that accesses the current user. This code unfortunately executes **BEFORE the token is validated**. How do I make it execute afterwards?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.Use(async (httpContext, next) =>
       {
           // THIS CODE EXECUTES BEFORE THE TOKEN IS VALIDATED IN OnTokenValidated.
           var userName = httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated 
             ? httpContext.User.GetClaim("email")
             : "(unknown)";
           LogContext.PushProperty("ActiveUser", !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) ? userName : "(unknown)");
           await next.Invoke();
       });
```

Comment: Maybe a filter is a better way to go here.

Comment: can you elaborate? I need access to the context, obviously?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters (or maybe you can gleem a better idea from there)

Comment: @leppie, do you want to post a short answer to that effect, I will edit it, and add a code sample once you have, and accept the answer - it works much better as a filter.

Comment: nah, you can have it :D ping me for an upvote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you've found a good solution to your problem but I thought I'd add an answer to explain the behavior you're seeing.

Since you have multiple authentication schemes registered and none is the default, authentication does not happen automatically as the request goes through the pipeline. That's why the `HttpContext.User` was empty/unauthenticated when it went through your custom middleware. In this "passive" mode, the authentication scheme won't be invoked until it is requested. In your example, this happens when the request passes through your `AuthorizeFilter`. This triggers the JWT authentication handler, which validates the token, authenticates and sets the Identity, etc. That's why ([as in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274422/user-doesnt-seem-authenticated-in-the-pipline-insideuse-in-dotnetcore-2-0)) the `User` is populated correctly by the time it gets to your controller action.

It probably doesn't make sense for your scenario (since you're using both cookies and jwt)... however, if you did want the Jwt authentication to happen automatically, setting `HttpContext.User` for other middleware in the pipeline, you just need to register it as the default scheme when configuring authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

Comment: I will probably drop cookies at some point but wanted both working. I didn't foresee these tricky scenarios. Whilst my solution works - i am accepting your answer - it's a great explanation that will surely help other engineers grappling with bearer tokens.

Comment: @Peter, you mention that if one sets the default scheme the JWT authentication it should be called automatically and set the principal but I've tried that but it does not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just hit this problem and this answer is spot on. I did had several schemes and setting the default indeed triggered authentication and everything worked as expected. What I did which worked (although I'm not sure if there's any impact) I moved the call to my middleware after the call to `app.UseAuthorization()`. Then my middleware was invoked with the user authenticated before reaching my controller. I'm in ASP.NET Core 3.1, with endpoint routing.

Answer (score 4):

based on @leppie's comment, here is a solution that works.

```
public class ActiveUserFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
        ActionExecutingContext context,
        ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var userName = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
        ? context.HttpContext.User.GetClaim("email")
        : "(unknown)";
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("ActiveUser", !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) ? userName : "(unknown)"))
            await next();
    }
}
```

Inserted as follows...

```
services.AddMvc(
    _ =>
    {
        _.Filters.Add(
           new AuthorizeFilter(
               new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                 JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                 IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
               .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                 .Build()));
        _.Filters.Add(new ActiveUserFilter());

        ...
```