# Is there a way to add claims in an ASP.NET Core middleware after Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this in my startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSwaggerWithUi();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMiddleware<SomeMiddleware>();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I need to add some additional claims AFTER the user is authenticated, but the middleware Invoke function always fires before Auth (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false). But when it hits the controller the user is authenticated fine.

Any idea what to do here? I've tried to put "app.UseAuthentication()" after calling `app.UseMiddleware` but it has no affect.

I'm currently using multiple Authentication schemes. I'm not sure if that has an affect.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this? I'm running on the exactly same prob (two JWT schemes, no default) and I also always get the user not authenticated in my middleware.

Comment: For those looking at the same issue, this answer explains why this happens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46309119/2689390. So, I moved my `app.UseMiddleware<SomeMiddleware>();` after `app.UseAuthorization()`.

Answer (score 51):

Yes it's possible, but instead of adding to the list of existing claims you have to add a new identity of type `ClaimsIdentity`.

```c#
public class SomeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SomeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.User != null && httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("SomeClaim", "SomeValue")
            };

            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
            httpContext.User.AddIdentity(appIdentity);                
        }

        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work if httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false?

Comment: This middleware has to be added after `UseAuthentication` middleware in `Configure` method which authenticates a user first. If  user is not authenticated for the purpose, but you still need to setup claims (not sure if it makes sense at all) you can remove this condition or implement different logic.

Comment: "but instead of adding to the list of existing claims you have to add a new identity of type" Actually you don't. You can add the claims to the existing identity. HttpContext.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().AddClaim(new Claim("user_id", "hello world"));

Answer (score 20):

You could write your own middleware to add new claims.

```
public class YourCustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public YourCustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.User != null && httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            httpContext.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().AddClaim(new Claim("your claim", "your field"));
        }
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

and in your app startup

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMiddleware<YourCustomMiddleware>();
```

Comment: For everyone still struggling with this, make sure that `app.UseAuthorization()` is after custom middleware

Comment: @donatasj87 that shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 14):

You can add another middleware immediately after the `UseAuthentication()` to add claims :

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.Use(async(context, next)=>{
    if(context.User !=null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
        // add claims here 
        context.User.Claims.Append(new Claim("type-x","value-x"));
    }
    await next();
});

//  call other middlewares 
app.UseMiddleware<SomeMiddleware>();
```

Comment: Tried this, no good. This works only if I have a default auth scheme.

Comment: @Yodacheese As far as I know, the `AuthenticationMiddleware` is invoked for every request. And  the claims will be added just after the authentication and before any other middlewares . It doesn't care whether there's a default scheme or not.  Could you please elaborate on `This works only if I have a default auth scheme` ?

Comment: The claims are somehow gone when I refresh the page. Any idea why?

Comment: @Enrico `context.User.Claims.Append` returns another list

Answer (score 9):

The preferred way for .NET Core 2.x is to use [IClaimsTransformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-2.0), this has a single method TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal) with the note

> Provides a central transformation point to change the specified
> principal. Note: this will be run on each AuthenticateAsync call, so
> its safer to return a new ClaimsPrincipal if your transformation is
> not idempotent.

Depending on the nature of the enrichment I add the claims to the existing authenticated identity or create a new identity with and mark that as authenticated. With the second idea you can make your method idempotent by checking for your custom identity before attempting the enrichment.

Comment: Could you add more information on how to actually use it? An example would be ideal.

Comment: Read More https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/samples?view=aspnetcore-2.1

GitHub Code
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Security/samples/ClaimsTransformation/ClaimsTransformer.cs

Comment: Promising BUT I have still not found a way to persist a claim (presumably add to existing identity, though possibly there is another way to persist it via a cookie/token). So I agree with the need for more info. I appreciate Sanket providing the links, but one of them is broken and the MS one doesn't talking about persisting a claim, merely intercepting the call for it.  Adding it to the ClaimsPrincipal passed into TransformAsync doesn't work, and you can't add it to the Identity of the ClaimsPrincipal passed in because at compile time that is just an IIdentity which has no claims ability.

Comment: Not sure why you want to persist it, the code that is performing the claims transformation already has the required values, if this is expensive to compute/retrieve you put a caching layer above it, for operational purposes you just add the claims every time you are told to do so.

Comment: Thx for response! I want to persist it because I am getting the info to add from the database and don't want to do that over and over. Before upgrading to Core I have persisted this kind of thing with session but I really don't want to have do it that way going forward. I am not familiar with caching in .NET beyond session and it does seem that the most appropriate way to do this is via authentication cookies. But I have yet to find a detailed solution for core 3.1 for basic silent windows auth as opposed to an external provider.

Comment: Have a look at IDistributedCache, there's an in-memory version of it or you can have a Redis instance if you need multi-node/region etc. Basically you put a caching version of your service over the one that retrieves from the database, i.e. a decorator, something like Polly can help here.

Comment: Found a Example using IClaimsTransformation https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-adding-claims-to-existing-identity/

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what do you want to do and which scheme you use.

For example, if you use `JwtBearer` then you could utilize `JwtBearerOptions.Events` to handle particular events raised by the middleware. You need to set that in your `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup` class.

That would give you more granular control of what precise case you want to have your Claims added to, for example, `OnTokenValidated`.

Comment: This is fine but a bit tedious. I have multiple schemes so JWT is just one, then I need to add the even on the custom auth scheme, at the same time I still want to use dependency injection so I have to resolve it.